# How long can you safely store home-prepared vacuum packed food for at home?

Tags: food-safety, sous-vide, marination

I have a consumer-grade vacuum sealer (Aicok) which I regularly use for sous-vide cooking with the manufacturer supplied bags. Under these different scenarios, how long can I keep food for, sealed and refrigerated properly, prior to and after cooking? I am concerned that a lack of air and the different ingredients (e.g. garlic, oil or dairy) pose a potential risk of botulism and decrease safe storage times. Conversely, will the vacuum sealing extend the shelf-life despite being a consumer, rather than a professional product? My estimate is 24 hours top for a marinade and 24 hours storage after cooking, but I realise this is probably extremely conservative.

1. Poultry e.g. chicken thighs, marinating in a citrus solution with fresh garlic?
2. Beef, e.g. steak, marinating in oil and fresh garlic?
3. Beef or chicken marinating in yoghurt or cream?
4. Any of the above, cooked sous-vide as appropriate, then rapidly cooled in cold water and refrigerated unopened ?

Comment: Vacuum sealing by itself does nothing, it's just a bag. Vacuum packed food that is shelf stable has been made safe after packaging. If you just seal your food in a bag it won't make any difference compared to other methods, see the duplicate for how long that will typically be.